# How to create signature Ed25519 in java

Tags: java, ed25519

I need to create a signature using Ed25519 by giving secret key as string and payload, which I use for binance api requests.

**The problem is** I found realisation below, from official binance java library, but it parses secret key from file and it is slow.
I want to create a signature by giving secret key as string directly, without having files

```
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new FileReader(pathToSecretKeyFile));
PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
byte[] privateKeyBytes = pemObject.getContent();
Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters privateKey = (Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters)        PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(privateKeyBytes);
pemReader.close();

byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Ed25519Signer signer = new Ed25519Signer();
signer.init(true, privateKey);
signer.update(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.length);
byte[] signatureBytes = signer.generateSignature();
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes);
```

**UPDATE**
I replace fileReader with StringReader as proposed

```
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(secret)); // secret key MCow********************fasaIo
    PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = pemObject.getContent();
```

And I get that pemObject now is null.
It throws on the last line "byte[] privateKeyBytes=pemObject.getContent();"

> NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()" because
> "pemObject" is null

Comment: in your code, you fetch the private key bytes from a PEM file - what format does your string have? Is it PEM format, but just not on disk, or hex encoded, or base64 encoded, or what?

Comment: @cyberbrain It's plain text format, I just specified path to .txt file where is my private key

Comment: If you want to import the PEM encoded key from a string and not from a file, you only need to use a `StringReader` instead of the `FileReader`.

Comment: @Topaco when i try PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(secretKey)); it throws "NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()" because "pemObject" is null"

Comment: I want to clarify secretKey is not formatted, I just take it directly from running app keys generator https://github.com/binance/asymmetric-key-generator/releases

Comment: So you have actually data in PEM format. You can either reuse it once you read it from disk, or specify it correctly (with all linebreaks etc.) as a string and use @Topaco s method. You should add the code that doesn't work for you to your question (you can fill all relevant letters of your file with "X" or similar to not reveal your secret key) together with the error message / stack trace you get for that.

Comment: Your key is missing header and footer, so it is not a valid PEM encoding. An invalid PEM key cannot be loaded with a `PemReader` neither with a `StringReader` nor with a `FileReader`.

Comment: @Topaco heck you are right! I just added comments  ---begin -- and --end-- private key and it works, THANK YOU!

Comment: @Topaco can you dublicate this as an answer so I'll mark it, or just close an issue